# R - Removing parts of value

Tags: r, dataframe, substitution

I have the following data frame:
Let's say that the data frame's name is "test".

```
        Persnr    Date AmountHolidays
1    55312 X201101            0.0
2    55316 X201101            3.0
3    55325 X201101            0.0
4    76065 X201101            0.0
5    71928 X201101            1.0
6    72558 X201101            0.5
7    73045 X201101            0.0
8    77214 X201101            0.5
9   121216 X201101            2.0
10   71951 X201101            0.0
11   55312 X201102            0.0
12   55316 X201102            3.0
13   55325 X201102            0.0
```

I want to delete all the X in front of the Date values. I've tried the sub function but it returns the data in plain text rather than a data frame..
This is what I tried:

```
dx<-sub("X(\\d{6})","\\1",test)
```

Comment: Try `test$Date <- sub("^X","",test$Date))`

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, I'd like to maintain the data frame as shown in the description. Only the values in the column Date has to be changed a bit.

Comment: I already solved my problem. In my first import function, all the dates were rownames. I first deleted the Xs with the `colnames(test)<-sub('X(\\d{6})','\\1', colnames(test))` before the Transpose function. This way, I did not need to edit the values since all the Xs already are deleted in the column headers. 
Afterwards, I transposed it and voila. Done. I think my brain went to sleep. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
require(stringr)
df$Date <- str_replace(df$Date,"X","")
```

Store your data in a dataframe df, and replace each X in your Date column with nothing, and you will get what you need.